# Feature-length animated movie from 80s or early 90s about humans avoiding androids

Tags: story-identification, androids

Back somewhere between 1995 and 1998 I have watched feature-length animated movie on home video. Sadly, tape was broken and I have never seen last 15-20 minutes. Animation quality was remarkably better than anything on TV at that time, so I think it was relatively new then. I don't remember anything from plot for certain, probably because I was too young to understand any of it (but hey, if it's animated it must be for children, right?).

What I do remember, though:

- There were only two main human characters - male and female. I'd say they were in 20s. Female might have been introduced in later part of the movie. If there were other humans, they didn't play significant enough role for me to remember them.
- There were a lot of androids, all looking exactly the same. They were painted black or dark-grey. Being androids, they were very human-like. I think they had blank heads, as if wearing helmets. I think they had very smooth movements and maybe main characters initially thought that they are humans?
- Androids had some specific, in-universe name. I think it did end with "-oid". It might have been in a title of movie.
- Main characters preferred to avoid these androids, rarely engaging in open confrontation.
- I don't remember any cities, forests, seas or grasslands. Most of the action was out in open air on some desert and/or rocky area, like real-world planet Mars.
- Art style was realistic. Think of something similar to [The End of Evangelion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQrXRBh94IA).
- Colors were rather dim, with heavy usage of dark orange/red.
- There was shooting. I think that shooting device had big caliber, like [Samus' in Metroid games](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/df/00/db/df00db42a644e4c63788ddacbb09e228.jpg). It shot laser beams or some kind of waves. Humans definitely shot at androids, but I don't remember if androids ever shot back.
- I think androids were empty inside. Main characters might have discovered that when they shot android for the first time and investigated the body.
- I think that close to end there was a scene with human(s?) floating in some reddish substance. That might have been a dream, some kind of out-of-body experience or them dying.

So, I remember rather visuals than plot, making it much harder for me to find. I did went through some "100 of best animes" lists and Wikipedia list on robot characters, but couldn't find it. So far I am only sure that it wasn't something from [Robot Carnival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Carnival).

Does anyone remember that movie and can name it?

Comment: Do you, by chance, know it's country of origin..? What is it's style..?

Perhaps Rene Laloux's 1988 'Gandahar' ..?

If a Japanese anime-style, the only ones I can think of--and I don't these fit--are 'Patlabor' (1989), 'Patlabor 2' (1993) and 'A Wind Named Amnesia' (1990)...

Although older (and these are also a stretch): 'Phoenix 2772' (1980), 'Andromeda Stories' (1982), or 'Venus Wars' (1989)...

Comment: @wcullen If you make "Gandahar" an answer, I will accept it. It is this movie! I see now that some of my hints were actually misleading (there are other people in movie, there is nature, blue is used more than red/orange, it's androids who shoot), but a lot check. That movie was originally released under title "Ferroids vs. Gandaharians" in my country, so it checks as well. Animation might not be as good as I remember, but art style definitely stands out. On a side - judging by nudity alone, this is definitely not children movie. What my parents were thinking when they let me watch it?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Survey says! [*Gandahar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandahar_(film))  :-P

> The peaceful people of Gandahar are suddenly attacked by an army of automatons known as the Men of Metal, who march through the villages and kidnap their victims by turning them to stone. The resulting statues are collected and then transferred to their base. At the capital city of Jasper, the Council of Women orders Sylvain to investigate. On his journey, he encounters the Deformed, a race of mutant beings who were accidentally created via genetic experimentation by Gandahar’s scientists. Despite their resentment, they are also threatened by the Men of Metal and offer to help Sylvain.

Glad I could help (yeah, what WERE your parents thinking! :-P)